# How to write a function which has 2 nested functions inside and let computes sum / difference for any number of given items?

Tags: python

I have to write a function which has 2 nested functions inside and computes only sum or difference of as many numbers as we want. Every equation end with "=". I wrote sth like this but it still doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

```
def calculator(x: int):
    
    def operation(operator: str):

        def calculation(y: int):
            while operator != "=":
                if operators[i] == "=":
                    result -= digits[j]
                elif operators[i] == "+":
                    result += digits[j]
                else:
                    break
            return result
        return operator
    return calculator(result)
```

Function should work like that:

```
calculator(1)('+')(4)('-')(2)('=')
```

The result is 3. I can't use any package import or global variables.

Comment: You are never executing or returning the inner functions. They have thus no use.

Comment: return operation not operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a dictionary to define your operations, and make a very readable and simple function with space for expansion:

```py
def calc(a: int): return lambda op: {
    '+': lambda b: calc(a+b),
    '-': lambda b: calc(a-b),
    '/': lambda b: calc(a/b),
    '*': lambda b: calc(a*b),
}.get(op, a)

print(calc(2)('+')(3)('-')(10)('/')(10)('*')(-100)('='))
```

Answer (score 2):

Deducing from the form of the input, you need to return "functions" each time. One way of doing that is to use `lambda`:

```py
def calculator(x: int):
    def operation(op: str, x: int):
        if op == '=':
            return x
        else:
            return lambda _: calculation(_, op, x)

    def calculation(y: int, op: str, x: int):
        if op == '+':
            return lambda _: operation(_, x + y)
        else:
            return lambda _: operation(_, x - y) # mind the order of x & y

    return lambda _: operation(_, x)

print(calculator(1)('+')(4)('-')(2)('=')) # 3
print(calculator(3)('-')(10)('+')(6)('=')) # -1
```

For example, consider `calculator(1)('+')(4)('-')(2)('=')`. The first part `calculator(1)('+')` means that `calculator(1)` itself is a function, which is then to be applied with an argument `('+')`. So `calculator(x)` need to return a function `operation`.

Also you might want to record the result (`1` in this case), by passing it to `operation`; that's why I added a parameter `x` (meaning the current result) to `operation`. Then I used `lambda x: operation(_, x)` to return a "partial function".

By the same reasoning, `operation` returns `calculation`, which in turns returns `operation` and so on, until `operation` is given with `'='`.